# I want to collapse table just click first row

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table which have some rows collapsible. When I click any rows, all table collapsed.(except first row)

But I want to collapse all table when **just I click first row**. So the other rows will not collaps the table.

Here is my code:

```
    <table  id="customers2" style="width:100%" onclick="expandCollapseTable(this)">
        //first row
        <tr class="gradient">
        <th  style="width:60%">Fruits</th>
        <th  style="width:40%">Value</th>
        </tr>
        //second row            
        <tr style="display:none">
             <td>Apple</td>
             <td>10</td>
        </tr>
        //third row         
        <tr style="display:none">
             <td>Orange</td>
             <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Here is my JS code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function expandCollapseTable(tableObj)
    {
        var rowCount = tableObj.rows.length;
        for(var row=1; row<rowCount; row++)
        {
            rowObj = tableObj.rows[row];
            rowObj.style.display = (rowObj.style.display=='none') ? '' : 'none';
        }
        return;
    }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modify your function to this;

```
function expandCollapseTable(tableObj) {
   var tableObj = document.getElementById("customers2");
   var firstRow = tableObj.rows[0];
   if (firstRow.style.display == 'none') {
       firstRow.style.display = '';
   } else {
       firstRow.style.display = 'none';
   }
}
```

In this function, we're getting the first row of the table using `tableObj.rows[0]`. Then, we're checking if the display style of this row is 'none'. If it is, we're setting it to an empty string to make it visible. If it's not 'none', we're setting it to 'none' to hide it.

This way, when you click on the first row, the table will collapse or expand. However, when you click on the other rows, nothing will happen because this function isn't attached to them.

I also modify you html to this;

```
<table id="customers2" style="width:100%">
   <!--first row-->
   <tr class="gradient" onclick="expandCollapseTable(this)">
       <th style="width:60%">Fruits</th>
       <th style="width:40%">Value</th>
   </tr>
   <!--second row-->
   <tr>
       <td>Apple</td>
       <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <!--third row-->
   <tr>
       <td>Orange</td>
       <td>20</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

As you notice, I've moved the `onclick` attribute from the `table` element to the `tr` element of the first row. Now, the `expandCollapseTable` function will be called when you click on the first row, but not when you click on the other rows.

**Modified Code**

```js
function expandCollapseTable() {
   var tableObj = document.getElementById("customers2");
   var rowCount = tableObj.rows;
   for (var row = 1; row < rowCount.length; row++) {
       if (rowCount[row].style.display === 'none') {
           rowCount[row].style.display = '';
       } else {
           rowCount[row].style.display = 'none';
       }
   }
}
```

```css
table, tr, th, td{
   border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<table id="customers2" style="width:100%">
   <!--first row-->
   <tr class="gradient" onclick="expandCollapseTable()">
      <th style="width:60%">Fruits</th>
      <th style="width:40%">Value</th>
   </tr>
   <!--second row-->
   <tr>
       <td>Apple</td>
       <td>10</td>
   </tr>
   <!--third row-->
   <tr>
       <td>Orange</td>
       <td>20</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your interest. But it didn't work. Can you try it please?

Comment: Bu it collapsed just the first row. I think I explained it wrong. My problem is when I click the any rows, The tabel collapse all.I want to collapse all rows (except first row) when I clicked just the first row.

Comment: thank a lot dude

Answer (score 0):

-html

```
<table id="customers2" style="width: 100%">
  <thead>
    <tr class="gradient">
      <th style="width: 60%">Fruits</th>
      <th style="width: 40%">Value</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Apple</td>
      <td>10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Orange</td>
      <td>20</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

-javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const table = document.querySelector("table");
  const thead = document.querySelector("thead");
  const tbody = document.querySelector("tbody");
  thead.addEventListener(
    "click",
    () =>
      (tbody.style.display = tbody.style.display == "none" ? "" : "none")
  );
</script>
```

I think in you function, it's not good to loop every tr.

And also your first row is maybe heading.

So you have to seperate your first with body like I did.

Ok?